# SQL LINQ Evaluate Comma-Separated String Contains Value

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am using EFCore Linq and run into a problem. I have a table that stores a comma-separated string and I need to use it in where clause to filter only those containing certain value. Here is my Linq:

```
var volunteers = context.Volunteers
               .Where(x => x.StatusId == 1
                     && x.RoleIds.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.None).Contains("1")
                ).ToList();
```

The column is RoleIds. The error I received is Linq query cannot be translated. What do I need to do here? Thanks!

Comment: The issue is that there probably are no SQL functions which can split a string and/or check if a string array contains a string and/or EFCore hasn’t implemented the mapping between these SQL functions and the C# functions. You could try `x.RoleIds.StartsWith("1,") || x.RoleIds.Contains(",1,") || x.RoleIds.EndsWith(",1") || x.RoleIds == "1")`, which should be same by checking if the first item is 1, an inner item is 1, the last item is 1, or there is only one item 1.

Comment: Thanks, I did this and it works: (x.RoleIds + ",").Contains("1,")

Comment: Please mind that your shortened form will also find 11, 21, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder ckuri. The actual number are much larger and unique. Should be OK. But good point tho!

Comment: Also note that `"1,"` won't match if the role ID is the last in the string, hence the need for all four tests.

Comment: Are these numbers or strings? i.e. can/should you parse them?
`.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList()` and then check for value/range or whatever is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are okay with using LINQKit (or rolling your own focused version), you can create extensions to handle the testing for you:

```
public static class IQueryableExt { // using LINQKit
    // string fieldExpr(T row) - function returning multiple value string field to test
    // delimiter - string separator between values in test field
    // value - string value to find in values of test field
    // dbq.Where(r => fieldExpr(r).Split(delimiter).Contains(value))
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereSplitContains<T>(this IQueryable<T> dbq, Expression<Func<T, string>> fieldExpr, string delimiter, string value) {
        var pred = PredicateBuilder.New<T>(r => fieldExpr.Invoke(r) == value);
        pred = pred.Or(r => fieldExpr.Invoke(r).StartsWith(value + delimiter));
        pred = pred.Or(r => fieldExpr.Invoke(r).EndsWith(delimiter + value));
        pred = pred.Or(r => fieldExpr.Invoke(r).Contains(delimiter + value + delimiter));

        return dbq.Where((Expression<Func<T, bool>>)pred.Expand());
    }

    // values - string values, one of which to find in values of test field
    // string fieldExpr(T row) - function returning multiple value string field to test
    // delimiter - string separator between values in test field
    // dbq.Where(r => values.Any(value => fieldExpr(r).Split(delimiter).Contains(value)))
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereAnySplitContains<T>(this IQueryable<T> dbq, IEnumerable<string> values, Expression<Func<T, string>> fieldExpr, string delimiter) {
        var pred = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();
        foreach (var value in values) {
            pred = pred.Or(r => fieldExpr.Invoke(r) == value);
            pred = pred.Or(r => fieldExpr.Invoke(r).StartsWith(value + delimiter));
            pred = pred.Or(r => fieldExpr.Invoke(r).EndsWith(delimiter + value));
            pred = pred.Or(r => fieldExpr.Invoke(r).Contains(delimiter + value + delimiter));
        }

        return dbq.Where((Expression<Func<T, bool>>)pred.Expand());
    }
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereSplitContainsAny<T>(this IQueryable<T> dbq, Expression<Func<T, string>> fieldExpr, string delimiter, IEnumerable<string> values) =>
        dbq.WhereAnySplitContains(values, fieldExpr, delimiter);
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereSplitContainsAny<T>(this IQueryable<T> dbq, Expression<Func<T, string>> fieldExpr, string delimiter, params string[] values) =>
        dbq.WhereAnySplitContains(values, fieldExpr, delimiter);

    // values - string values, all of which to find in values of test field
    // string fieldExpr(T row) - function returning multiple value string field to test
    // delimiter - string separator between values in test field
    // dbq.Where(r => values.All(value => fieldExpr(r).Split(delimiter).Contains(value)))
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereAllSplitContains<T>(this IQueryable<T> dbq, IEnumerable<string> values, Expression<Func<T, string>> fieldExpr, string delimiter) {
        var pred = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();
        foreach (var value in values) {
            var subPred = PredicateBuilder.New<T>(r => fieldExpr.Invoke(r) == value);
            subPred = subPred.Or(r => fieldExpr.Invoke(r).StartsWith(value + delimiter));
            subPred = subPred.Or(r => fieldExpr.Invoke(r).EndsWith(delimiter + value));
            subPred = subPred.Or(r => fieldExpr.Invoke(r).Contains(delimiter + value + delimiter));
            pred = pred.And(subPred);
        }

        return dbq.Where((Expression<Func<T, bool>>)pred.Expand());
    }
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereSplitContainsAll<T>(this IQueryable<T> dbq, Expression<Func<T, string>> fieldExpr, string delimiter, IEnumerable<string> values) =>
        dbq.WhereAllSplitContains(values, fieldExpr, delimiter);
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereSplitContainsAll<T>(this IQueryable<T> dbq, Expression<Func<T, string>> fieldExpr, string delimiter, params string[] values) =>
        dbq.WhereAllSplitContains(values, fieldExpr, delimiter);
}
```

With these extensions, your query would be:

```
var volunteers = context.Volunteers.Where(x => x.StatusId == 1)
                                   .WhereSplitContains(r => r.RoleIds, ",", "1")
                                   .ToList();
```

If you had multiple values, you could use the other variations:

```
var volunteers = context.Volunteers.Where(x => x.StatusId == 1)
                                   .WhereSplitContainsAny(r => r.RoleIds, ",", "1", "2")
                                   .ToList();
```

Comment: That works very well NetMage, thanks a lot! Just another thought -- how would I modify the extension so it will take in a list of string values instead of just a single value "1"?

Comment: @Franky Would you want an OR or AND handling of the list of values?

Comment: @Franky I added variations for a list of values.