# Expression is not supported. LinQ

Tags: linq

Good afternoon!
I have a table with a string field with such data:
'1,2,4,5,8,10,15,20,35'
And would like to select entries where this field contains value 5.
But I can not use Contains, because I will get entries consists not only 5, but 15, 35, for example.
I tried to do something like:

```
result = uow.Query<MyObject>().Where(x => x.MyProperty.Split(',').Contains("5")).Any();
```

But got the exception about expression is not supported. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `StartsWith`, `EndsWith` and `Contains`:

```
result = uow.Query<MyObject>().Where(x => x.StartsWith("5,") || x.EndsWith(",5") || x.Contains(",5,")).Any();
```

Also, you could use the extensions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64072089/2557128).